# rails -v errors when setting up rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to set up an environment as per this tutorial http://railstutorial.org/book#sec:1.2.2.3 however I get the below error when running 'rails -v'

```
bash-3.2$ rails -v
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem rails (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
        from /Users/sandbox1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
        from /Users/sandbox1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in `gem'
        from /usr/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
```

Has anyone had this before?

Comment: have you install rails ? gem install rails ?

Comment: Path variable is - bash-3.2$ echo $PATH
/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tutorial/bin:/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/sandbox1/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin
bash-3.2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incase anyone else has this problem and the marked answer doesn't solve it, here is what fixed it for me:

**Don't use sudo.**

- "When you do sudo you are running
  commands as root, another user in
  another shell and hence all of the
  setup that RVM has done for you is
  ignored while the command runs under
  sudo (such things as GEM_HOME,
  etc...). So to reiterate, as soon as
  you 'sudo' you are running as the
  root system user which will clear out
  your environment as well as any files
  it creates are not able to be
  modified by your user and will result
  in strange things happening. (You
  will start to think that someone has
  a voodoo doll of your
  application...)"

Taken from [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/)

Comment: This is most likely the solution if you came to this page and are using rvm

Answer (score 0):

resolved by running "rvm gemset update"